# Universal MediaElement double tapped event

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, mediaelement

Someone knows, why double tap event won't fire on MediaElement, while in full window mode? Simple as that, when in FullWindow Double Tapped event won't trigger! Windows 10 Universal App!

```
private void MediaElement_DoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.IsFullWindow = !mediaElement.IsFullWindow; 

    }
```

Comment: You should use more words to explain your problem. It is better to add some codes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found a way to make this work, in place of mediaelement.DoubleTapped use

```
    mediaElement.TransportControls.DoubleTapped += TransportControls_DoubleTapped;

    private void TransportControls_DoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.IsFullWindow = !mediaElement.IsFullWindow;
    }
```

But there is a problem, you can double tap on controls and it will work!